# js reduce to group on a key's value with duplicates

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

How can I use `.reduce()` to group by the value  - so if I have the following:

```
const arr = [
 { 
   id: 1,
   value: 'abc',
   othervalue: '123'
 },
 { 
   id: 2,
   value: 'def',
   othervalue: '123'
 },
 { 
   id: 3,
   value: 'def',
   othervalue: '123'
 },
 { 
   id: 4,
   value: 'ghi',
   othervalue: '123'
 }
]
```

I want this :

```
  {
   'abc' : [{id:1, value:'abc', othervalue: '123'}]
   'def' : [{id:2, value:'def', othervalue: '123'}, {id:3, value:'def', othervalue:'123'}],
   'ghi' : [{id:4, value:'ghi', othervalue: '123'}]
  }
```

I tried this but it didn't work:

arr.reduce( (acc,p) => ({...acc, [p.value]:p }))

Comment: fix your expected output, cant tell if its supposed to be an object or an array with an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is close, but make sure to:

- spell `acc` properly
- keep the previous values in the array with `(acc[p.value]||[]).concat(p)`
- provide an initial value, `{}` as the second arg

```js
arr.reduce((acc,p) => ({ ...acc, [p.value]: (acc[p.value]||[]).concat(p) }), {})
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not a tiny one liner, but it's readable

```js
const arr = [{
    id: 1,
    value: 'abc',
    othervalue: '123'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: 'def',
    othervalue: '123'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    value: 'def',
    othervalue: '123'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    value: 'ghi',
    othervalue: '123'
  }
]

let grouped = arr.reduce((b, a) => {
  b[a.value] = b[a.value] || [];
  b[a.value].push(a);
  return b
}, {})

console.log(grouped)
```

Comment: Just in case you find it useful: this `b[a.value] = b[a.value] || []` could be "simplified"  with `b[a.value] ??= []`.